# online classes for sql server administration?

Tags: sql-server

my company wants to sponsor me for some online sql server DBA classes. can someone please recommend a beginner's class to me?

Comment: You'd probably have more luck on ServerFault, though it's probably still off-topic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppDev's online courses are pretty good.
For around 1000 USD, you can have a lots of excellent courses on different subjects: http://www.appdev.com/

PS: I don't work for them, but I'm an happy customer.

Answer (score 1):

Start at the SQL Server 2008 training portal, [here](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/training/sql-server.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the next links:

- [sqldbatraining](http://sqldbatraining.com/)
- [cbtplanet](http://www.cbtplanet.com/distance-learning/microsoft-sql-server.htm)
- [sqlservermasters](http://www.sqlservermasters.com/sql_server_2008_dba_modules.html)
- And [this](http://sqlcourse.com/) is a good basic tutorial for SQL instructions.